# Escaping single quotes in resource xml for Android

Tags: android, xml, resources

I have a file with strings in my ../res/values/strings.xml, which I try to source for my project. This works fine with normal texts.
Problem : I have single quotes in my texts and I try to escape them. Many sources suggest to escape it with `&apos;` in XML Files.

But this does not work for me in my Eclipse Android Project. When I do a clean project, it shows errors in my Code. (R.class)

```
<string name="mystring_id">&apos;Hello&apos;</string>
```

Howto escape properly ?

Comment: @Karakuri: Post this as your answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `\'` in your string resources.

Answer (score 10):

Use double quotes:

```
<string name="mystring_id">"'Hello'"</string>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's by far cleaner than having to escape every other character in big blocks of text.

Answer (score 5):

you need to escape the apostrophe by using

```
\ before '
```

etc didn't should be like

```
didn\'t
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I attempt to run my app using this technique, the compiler removes my \ and then complains about not escaping apostrophe.

Comment: @Essah I just went through this as well. The mistake was trying to edit the generated intermediate files instead of the original strings.xml.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <string name="forgot_password_body" tools:ignore="StringEscaping">Mother's name</string>
```

using `{tools:ignore="StringEscaping"}` this tools attribute you can add single quote like you want